# Spring test 4.2.5 says "he attribute classes is undefined for the annotation type ContextConfiguration"

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm working on project with spring-framework 4.2.5, I'm configuring tests with JUnit 4.12 and spring-test 4.2.5, I have a config class annotated with `@Configuration` and `@ComponentScan`.

When I annotate the test with:

`@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyConfigClass.class)`

Eclipse gives an error and says:

```
The attribute 'classes' is undefined for the annotation type ContextConfiguration
```

Comment: Then either you imported another ContextConfiguration from some other library, or you have an older version of Spring in the classpath. When you go to the implementation of ContextConfiguration, which jar file opens in the project view?

Comment: Yeah! that was, I just see in my pom.xml I have 2.5 in spring-test, it's really embarassing, thanks for your time